# Set SharePoint Group Owner of a SharePoint group through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I'm trying to set up a SharePoint group as a group owner:

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://sitecollection -Identity "Channel" -Owner "Music"
```

The error is:

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup : The specified user Music could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: At least in some context it wasn't possible to add a group to own another group. It was somehow related to user permissions, so likely applicable to your case as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to get the `SPOGroup` and then pass it to the  `Set-SPOSiteGroup` as below:

```
$ownerGroup = Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection" -Group "Music"

Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site $siteUrl -Identity "Channel" -Owner $ownerGroup
```

**Update** - not really sure why its not working, but the below code is working for me. I have used CSOM with powershell to set the group owner.

```
$username = "username@tenantname.sharepoint.com" 
$password = "password" 
$url = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 

# the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:\Lib.. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 


# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

$ownerGroup = $clientContext.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Music");

$visitorGroup = $clientContext.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Channel");
$visitorGroup.Owner = $ownerGroup;
#set group view membership
$visitorGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = $false;
$visitorGroup.Update();
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info but still not working.. I'm getting the error "Get-SPOSiteGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name".. What should I change?

Comment: @PeterSmp - my bad, there was error in syntax. It should be `Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site`, can you check code now ?

Comment: Now is different: Set-SPOSiteGroup : The specified user
Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOSiteGroup could not be found (I think he's expecting a user, not a group, probably)

Comment: Can you check with updated answer ?

Comment: Thank's a lot! It is working now! do you know if  there's a way to use CSOM with Powershell to specify the group settings for a group? "Who can view the membership of the group? "Group members of everyone" ?

Comment: Glad i could help, please mark it as an answer if the code is working as expected :) , regarding the `who can view membership` ,  you should set it as `$visitorGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = $true(or $false)`. You can view the properties at this link and set it accordingly - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.group_properties.aspx

Comment: can you help me doing it?

Comment: check updated code. Using this approach, you can set the group settings

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this may be It will help you

```
            #Get the SPWeb
            $web = Get-SPWeb http://url_to_web

            #Get the Group
            $group = $web.SiteGroups["Group Name"]

            #Get the User 
            $user = $web.EnsureUser("domain\username")

            #Assign that user as the owner
            $group.Owner = $user

            #Update the Group
            $group.Update()
```

Comment: this is for sharepoint on prem, not online

Comment: I have some question. Are you able to connect SharePoint Online using PowerShell?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected, I can execute the set-spositegroup by using a username instead of a group